# Passing array to view in codeinghter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem in `MVC`, i want to pass an array named as `$store_array` to view, how is it possible, code is given below, please comment.

```
print_r($store_array);
$this->data['store_array'] = $store_array;
$this->_load_view('clienth/domainlist');
```

Comment: Check CodeIgniter's [documentation on views](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you use `$this->_load_view()` , It should be `$this->load->view()`. See the difference?

Use:

```
$this->data['store_array'] = $store_array;
$this->load->view('clienth/domainlist', $this->data);
```

The second parameter from `$this->load->view()` is the data you pass to the view.

Comment: it does not work, i want to send you a screenshot, plz provide me your email id

Comment: in your view try `var_dump($store_array)` . What do you see?

Comment: You forgot `$` while passing from view.

Answer (score 1):

try to pass `$this->data` in `view()`

```
print_r($store_array); 
$this->data['store_array'] = $store_array; 
$this->load->view('clienth/domainlist', $this->data);
```

also function call syntax will be

```
$this->load->view() // not with _(underscore)
```

and get array on view `print_r($store_array);`

Answer (score 0):

On the controller:

```
$this->data['store_array'] = $an_array;
$this->load->view('clienth/domainlist',$this->data);
```

On the view you just access that array by referencing:

```
foreach ($store_array as $item) 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Dear all,I have tried all methods mentioned above, actually all above methods are same, but i didn,t get any value on view side, when i print var_dump($_REQUEST), nothing display.................what i do now????

Comment: try `var_dump($store_array)`

Answer (score 0):

ok since there are so many answers :-)

i'm going to suggest that you do not use $this->data and just do it like:

```
$data['store_array'] = $store_array; 
$this->load->view('clienth/domainlist', $data);
```

its shorter and its easier to read.

---

otherwise you could do this

```
$this->store_array = $store_array;

// note that i am NOT passing store_array to view here  
$this->load->view('clienth/domainlist');
```

but because $this-> is magic

in your 'clienth/domainlist' View store_array is now available

```
   echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->store_array) .  '</pre>';
```

but i usually like method one better because you can see exactly what is being passed to the view.